# MCS Character mouth remains open after assigning mocap

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, animator, mo-cap

I have **[MCS Female Character](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/45807)** where I can assigned Mocap to my character. I have downloaded [**Mixamo**](https://www.mixamo.com) animation and assigned this to the character but the problem is, the character mouth remains open. I am not **3D Artist** or Animation guy, so here are my question.

1. How can I solve mouth open problem in unity?
2. What is the reason that mouth is open? Either mocap data has open the mouth or what else problem?

I have also assigned [**Huge Mocap FBX library**](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19991) animation to my character but problem is still same.

Comment: How is this related to C# (or programming at all)? You don't seem to have any code. Also please pay attention what tags you are adding to your question ("Animator" is not related to Unity at all). You'd probably be better off asking the developers of the products you are using (or finding an animator to take a look at it, the two most likely suspects would be the rig or the animation data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go To **M3D character manager** component in your character
2. Go to **Advanced**
3. Check (True) **Force Jaw Shut**

Thanks to MCS team for answer